# Is there any downloader library like Android Asynchronous Http Client [Java]

Tags: java, android

I have found Android Asynchronous Http Client library from google: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/
This is awesome lib for Android. But it's not have download function. Is there any lib which support async download function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use an AsyncTask and in the doInBackground method, download your file.

Try com.github.droidfu

Comment: I want a lib which support auto-retry :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use intentservice http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html